# Comment out methods using the Outline view in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I was wondering if there exists some sort of plugin for Eclipse to add onto the Outline view that will comment out blocks of methods.

This would be useful for me during unit testing and I want to retest specific failing methods while leaving alone the ones I know will pass.

My current workaround is simply using

```
/* 
     unit test code
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select blocks then do CTRL+/ and Ctrl+Shift+/

Ctrl+/ comments all selected lines each with //

Ctrl+Shift+/ Comments out all selected lines with /* */

Doing it again uncomments

Comment: Sure, yeah, that I am aware of, looking for a more fluid way to select and comment out the entire block of code

Answer (score 0):

To select an entire method from within a method (may require multiple chains), press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>. To traverse methods, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>.

Depending on where you are in the method, it will select the following things in ascending order (approximately).

1. parent object
2. individual statement or method call
3. full line
4. enclosing brackets
5. enclosing if/else, for, while loop structures
6. method declarations
7. class declarations

Then, using the comment shortcut provided in the other answer, you can quickly navigate and comment.